# Create shaded and non shaded jars in Maven in same module?

Tags: maven

Is it possible to create 2 jars upon maven build:

1. Shaded jar (uber)
2. Non shaded jar

I'd like to have both published to maven local. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration can be given as follows will create an jar file (done by default) and the following will create a `xyz-1.0-shaded.jar` supplemental:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```